# How to link data from spreadsheet into google site

Tags: spreadsheet, google-sites

I want to link data from spreadsheet to my google site as when I edit in spreadsheet, the data on website is automatically change as data in spreadsheet. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you explain what you've tried so far?  In particular, could you add a [Short, Self-Contained, (Compilable) Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)? That's the best way to get help on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

The simplest is to use a 'Chart'. Just insert it like you would anything else via *Insert-> Chart -> Select your spreadsheet.* Depending on the data you have, there will only really be a few options of displaying it. But you can select which sheet and the cell ranges. If you don't need to do anything crazy with it, then this should be fine.

Alternately, you can make a small Apps Script which will display the data in a grid. Then you have full control over it...

Something like:

```
function doGet(e){   
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.sheetid);
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("YOUR SHEET NAME");
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var dataRange =  range.getValues();
var grid = app.createGrid(range.getNumRows(), range.getNumColumns());
for (var row = 0; row < dataRange.length; row++) {
  for (var col = 0; col < dataRange[0].length; col++) {//1 so as to skip the header
    grid.setText(row, col, dataRange[row][col])
  }
}
 app.add(grid); 
 return app;  
}
```

Note: SheetID (and whatever else, like the sheet name) is passed in as an html query parameter which you must manually supply in the HTML edit of the page after adding the Gadget. This can be found in the properties of the spreadsheet (file->properties)